# How to create shortcut for Worklight on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

Is it possibile create keyboard shortcuts for the IBM Worklight plugin in Eclipse?

In particular I would like the shortcut for the actions: "Run on Worklight Server Development" and "Xcode project."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to create your own custom keyboard shortcuts on-top of the provided keyboard shortcuts by the Studio plug-in.

The available shortcuts are:

For "Run on MobileFirst Development Server" (when right-clicking on the my-projects\apps\my-app folder:)
[image]

For "Xcode project" (when right-clicking on the my-projects\apps\my-app\iphone folder:)
[image]

Comment: Hi, i tried the command for Xcode Project which is "Option + Command + Alphabet X and Alphabet I" but it is not working. would you guys pls help?